# grab data from mysql and echo into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am quite new to PHP and have a problem that I am running into.

At the moment my site is locked to only IP addresses I put into my code manually. I am trying to automate this by inserting ip addresses into mysql database.

Currently my `index.php` file looks like this -

```
$allowlist = array(
'86.162.244.16','79.88.293.33'
);
```

As you can see above, those are the IP addresses that do not get redirected to a 'coming soon' page.

I've created a table in my DB called allowedips, which is where I am storing the IP's I want to give access too.

How can I automatically grab the info from the DB and insert it into that array? Everything I have tried so far just stops the site from working.

So far I have tried

```
$allowlist = array(

$query1 = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM `allowedips`" );
while ( $all = mysql_fetch_object ( $query1 ) )
{
echo $all->ip;
}
);
```

Kind Regards,
Jay

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: can you post you have done so far?

Comment: Updated post above

Answer (score 0):

firstly, if you are grabbing data from the DB ...you can either grab it in form of an Associative array, Numerical array(sometimes Multidimensional Array if the Row count is more than one) or in form of Object....if you are using object oriented PHP......

for example:
$dbdata = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

the variable $dbdata is an associative array

if $dbdata = mysqql_fetch_array($query);
then the variable $dbdata is a numerical array..

to classically check the content of your variable you can use the var_dump() function......and then you can use the in_array() function to check if the ip_address are in the array....and that is;

```
if(in_array("THE_SPECIFIC_IP_ADDRESS", $arrayOfIPaddress)){
     echo"coming soon";
//enter any code you want here
}else{
    echo"not coming soon";
}
```